# Is this trigger bullkified?

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

Will this trigger work for bulk processing?

```
trigger ContactAfterInser1t on Dr_Invite__c (before insert, before update) {
    list<Dr_Invite__c> aList = new list<Dr_Invite__c>();

    Set<Id> DrId = new Set<Id>();
    Set<String> EntityId = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> NPISet = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> PECOSID = new Set<String>();
    List<Id>  LeadId= new List<Id>();
    List<Dr_Invite__c>  updaetDrInvite= new List<Dr_Invite__c>();

    for(Dr_Invite__c drIn:trigger.new){
           EntityId.add(drIn.fpn_entity_id__c); 
           NPISet.add(drIn.npi__c);
           PECOSID.add(drIn.pecos_group_pac_id__c); 

     }

    List<Dr_Invite__c> DrinviteList = [select id, lead__c, dr_name__c, fpn_entity_id__c, npi__c, pecos_group_pac_id__c from Dr_Invite__c where  
                                       fpn_entity_id__c IN :EntityId OR npi__c IN : NPISet 
                                       OR pecos_group_pac_id__c IN : PECOSID limit 1];
     if(DrinviteList.size()>0)
     {
        for(Dr_Invite__c drIn:trigger.new)
            {   
                for(Dr_Invite__c c:DrinviteList) 
                {    
                     if(c.fpn_entity_id__c==drIn.fpn_entity_id__c || c.npi__c == drin.npi__c || c.pecos_group_pac_id__c==drin.pecos_group_pac_id__c)
                     {
                         drIn.lead__c=c.lead__c;
                         aList.add(drIn);
                     }
                 }
            }
       }
    else
    {
         for(Dr_Invite__c drIn:trigger.new)
         {
             lead l = new lead();
             l.LastName=drIn.dr_name__c;
             l.Company='test';
             insert l;

             if(l.id != Null)
              drIn.lead__c=l.id;    
         }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is nit working as per functionality? Seems like you are matching/creating leads based on 3 fields with OR condition?

Answer (score 5):

No, this trigger violates the most basic rule of bulkification: never perform within a loop any action ruled by governor limits. That includes queries, DML, future calls, sending emails, and so on.

In this case, the violating code is in your else block.

**Not Bulkified**

```
for(Dr_Invite__c record : trigger.new)
{
    Lead l = new Lead();
    // set fields
    insert l;
}
```

**Bulkified**

```
List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
for (Dr_Invite__c record : trigger.new)
{
    leads.add(new Lead(
        LastName = record.Dr_Name__c
    ));
}
insert leads;
```

Now you won't exceed your DML Statement limit. It's also worth noting that setting fields in the SObject constructor using `Name=value` pairs is significantly faster than instantiating the record and setting each field individually.

---

If you want to set a lookup from the `Dr_Invite__c` record to the lead created for it, you can rely on the order being the same. You also don't need to check if the Id is populated after insert, since that is guaranteed.

```
insert leads;
for (Integer i = 0; i < trigger.new.size(); i++)
{
    trigger.new[i].Lead__c = leads[i].Id;
}
```

Comment: Ah good catch @Adrain!

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks. The criteria are probably still wrong, but that's a bit of a separate question. Seems like it should be ensuring that each inserted record has the `Lead__c` lookup populated, which is not what it's doing currently.

Comment: +1. I didn't see that coming. Just a polite inquiry on this `trigger.new[i].Lead__c = leads[i].Id;`, I believe it'll work if each trigger record corresponds to creation of a lead, else we would need to keep a separate list of trigger records as well?

Comment: @Mahmood Yes, that's correct. You would need to filter just the list of `Dr_Invite__c` records which need a `Lead` created in order to use index reliably.